# Can't get Cabal-install to work on my mac

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

So, I'm trying to get cabal installed so I can get quickcheck to work in haskell, but nothing seems to work. Whenever I try to run "cabal-install" in my terminal (on mac) I get the same message "command not found", I've looked at multiple different "solutions" and even "solutions" on the cabal website, but nothing seems to work. Any help at all would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`cabal-install` is a package. `cabal` is the executable/command installed by the `cabal-install` package. `cabal install` is a subcommand of the `cabal` command—it's the command `cabal` called with the argument `install`. Your full command "should" be `cabal install QuickCheck`, but there's no point in actually executing that command. If you have Cabal v1 or v2, `cabal install` refers to the version 1 install method, which is broken and dangerous. If you have Cabal v3, `cabal install` refers to the version 2 install method, where `cabal install QuickCheck` is pointless. It *will* install `QuickCheck`, but `QuickCheck` is just a library with no executables, so there's no point.

Assuming `cabal-install` is correctly installed (you should have access to the `cabal` command), you need to figure out what you're going to *do* with `QuickCheck`. If you just want to open a GHCi session, say `cabal v2-repl -b QuickCheck`. If you want to compile a bunch of files (i.e. you want something more "permanent"), you need to create a package, where the `<pkgname>.cabal` file contains something along the lines of

```
build-depends: base, QuickCheck, ..etc
```

When you build such a package with `cabal v2-build`, or you start GHCi with `cabal v2-repl -b QuickCheck`, `cabal` will go and install `QuickCheck` automatically if it needs to. This is why `cabal v2-install QuickCheck` is pointless.